# Using generic base class for WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

Why is this:

```
public abstract class WindowControls<T> : Window
```

not possible. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
    public partial class AnglesteelWindow : WindowControls<AngleSteel> {
    private UCListView uc;
    public AnglesteelWindow() {

        InitializeComponent();
        uc = new UCListView();
        uc.SubmitClick += new EventHandler(ButtonPressed);
        this.uc.grid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp +=
            new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(
                 this.MousePressed14<AngleSteel>);
        stkTest.Children.Add(uc);
        uc.amountLabel.Content = "Milimeter";
        uc.grid.ItemsSource = DatabaseLogic.MaterialTable("Anglesteel").DefaultView;
        base.Material(uc, "Anglesteel");
    }
}
```

I know how generics work, but don't know why it is not possible to make my AnglesteelWindow derive from WindowControls.
The error it gives me is the following:

> Base class of 'Name of the solution' differs from declared in other parts.

When i look at the so called other part it is the following:

```
    public partial class AnglesteelWindow : 
          WindowControls<AngleSteel> System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
```

This is made in the AnglesteelWindow.g.i.cs file. If i remove it from there it makes no difference at all.

Comment: Does this window have a XAML file?

Comment: The problem is not in your C# code, but in it's incompatibility with the XAML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding on @MichaelMairegger answer, you can reach your goal by creating another non-generic class that inherits from the generic class like this:

```
public abstract class WindowControlsOfAngleSteel : WindowControls<AngleSteel>
{

}
```

And make your window class inherit from it like this:

From XAML:

```
<ns:WindowControlsOfAngleSteel >

</ns:WindowControlsOfAngleSteel >
```

Where `ns` is the namespace where `WindowControlsOfAngleSteel` exists.

In code (optional):

```
public partial class AnglesteelWindow : WindowControlsOfAngleSteel
{

}
```

Comment: if you remove the `abstract` in the base class then the answer is correct.

Comment: @MichaelMairegger, why do you think that `abstract` needs to be removed? I actually tested this code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought defining a abstract class as root results in an error. Have never tried that.

Comment: The thing is that this would be used for 6 windows which each have a different name but the same functionality, so i would make 6 WindowControlsOfAnglesteel, that seems kinda much :s

Comment: Do they all need to inherit from `WindowControls<Anglesteel>` or some other `WindowControls<SomeThingelse>`?

Comment: Some other WindowControls. Anglesteel represents a type of material, there are 5 other materials aswell. So these would be others for the generic WindowControls<SomethingElse>

Comment: Then this might be the only option. I am not sure though. By the way, currently, WPF uses XAML2006. XML2009 supports generic types. Maybe a later version of WPF will support XML2009.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the inheritance tree. `AnglesteelWindow` is partial because it is also declared in AnglesteelWindow.xaml where the root element is `Window`. If you want to inherit from another class you have to replace there the `Window` root by your base class.

```
public class MyDerivedBaseWindow : Window {}



<ns:MyDerivedBaseWindow >
    <!-- WindowContent-->
</ns:MyDerivedBaseWindow >
```

But you cannot use a Generic class in XAML. You have to change your logic that the base-window-class that you want to use as window-root is non-generic.